# PHP and DB2 working together

Tags: php, db2

I'm trying to do this script:

```
//Agent D4 OFFLINE events last 24h

        $q_d4_offline_last24h = "select distinct NODE, LASTOCCURRENCE, INPS_CLOSE_TIMESTAMP
                                  from REPORTER.REPORTER_STATUS
                                  where ALERTKEY = 'M_SW_MID_MON_SER_STS_006C_ALL'
                                   and NODEALIAS like '%:D4'
                                   and LASTOCCURRENCE > DATE(CURRENT_DATE -1 DAYS)";


        $DB2_REPORTER_conn = new ldbproxy();
        if(!$DB2_REPORTER_conn->connect_db2("192.168.8.245:50001", "REPORTER", "itmuser", "tivoli")) die ('E:Connessione al DB2 fallita:' . $DB2_REPORTER_conn->errorMsg);
        $connettore = $DB2_REPORTER_conn->query($q_d4_offline_last24h) or die("E:Errore nella query: " . $DB2_REPORTER_conn->errorMsg);


      $rownum = count($DB2_REPORTER_conn->fetch($connettore));


      if($rownum > 0) {

        $prev_node=NULL;


      echo "\n - Eventi di offline relativi ad agent ITCAM for SOA rilevati nelle ultime 24 ore:\n\n";

        while($row = $DB2_REPORTER_conn->fetch($connettore)){



             if ( $row['NODE'] != $prev_node ) {

                echo "\n\t" . $row['NODE'];
                $prev_hostname = $row['NODE'];
             }

              echo "\n\t\tData inizio: " . substr($row['LASTOCCURRENCE'],0,-2);

              if($row['INPS_CLOSE_TIMESTAMP'] == '1970-01-01 01:00:00.0')
                echo "\n\t\tData fine: n/a";

                else
                  echo "\n\t\tData fine: " . substr($row['INPS_CLOSE_TIMESTAMP'],0,-2) . "\n";

        }
      }
```

Usually the query I use get out 3 rows as result.
I don't understand why in output I get only the last two rows, it jumps always the first row.

Can you help me?

Comment: Make sure you change your DB password now that you have posted this...

Answer (score 0):

This statement is fetching the first result row, and then not using it for anything.  So it gets discarded:

```
$rownum = count($DB2_REPORTER_conn->fetch($connettore));
```

If you are only dealing with a small number of rows, it will probably be more convenient to use [`fetchall`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).  This will get all rows at once, so you can check how many there are, and then use a loop to process them.

.

Comment: If I echo $rownum it gives me 3 as result.

Comment: Ah ok. I get it. So how to get the real number of rows and the rows themeselves?

Comment: I get: Fatal error: Call to undefined method ldbproxy::fetchall(). Inside ldbproxy what is the right command?

Comment: @Idro, I don't know what `ldbproxy()` is...you don't actually say how you are connecting so I don't know.

Comment: @Idro, here's the PHP DB2 library I'm aware of, but it doesn't match what you are doing in your code: http://php.net/manual/en/book.ibm-db2.php